# Uncaught (in promise) path not allowed on the configured scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fs, tauri

## Problem

I keep getting this Error with **read dir**, **createDir** works just fine and i got no errors here.

## Code

### Filetree.js

```
import { readDir,createDir, BaseDirectory } from '@tauri-apps/api/fs';
import { appDir } from '@tauri-apps/api/path';

let defineEntries = async () => {
  console.log("Loading Data");
  entries = await  readDir('test', new Uint8Array([]), { dir: BaseDirectory.Desktop, recursive: true });
  console.log("Success");
}
```

### Tauri.conf.json

```
"tauri": {
    "allowlist": {
      "fs": {
        "all": true,
        "readFile": true,
        "writeFile": true,
        "readDir": true,
        "copyFile": true,
        "createDir": true,
        "removeDir": true,
        "removeFile": true,
        "renameFile": true,
        "scope": ["$DESKTOP/*", "$DESKTOP/**", "$DESKTOP/test/*"]

      },
      "path": {
        "all": true
      }
    }
```

## Version

```
> tauriplayground@0.1.0 tauri
> tauri "info"


Environment
  › OS: Windows 10.0.19044 X64
  › Webview2: 103.0.1264.37
  › MSVC: 
      - Visual Studio Build Tools 2019
  › Node.js: 16.14.2
  › npm: 8.5.0
  › pnpm: Not installed!
  › yarn: 1.22.19
  › rustup: 1.24.3
  › rustc: 1.61.0
  › cargo: 1.61.0
  › Rust toolchain: stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc 

Packages
  › @tauri-apps/cli [NPM]: 1.0.0
  › @tauri-apps/api [NPM]: 1.0.1
  › tauri [RUST]: 1.0.0,
  › tauri-build [RUST]: 1.0.0,
  › tao [RUST]: 0.11.2,
  › wry [RUST]: 0.18.3,

App
  › build-type: bundle
  › CSP: unset
  › distDir: ../build
  › devPath: http://localhost:3000/
  › framework: React

App directory structure
  ├─ node_modules
  ├─ public
  ├─ src
  ├─ src-tauri
  └─ tree
```

## What i have tried

I alerady set the tauri.conf.json to:

- "scope": ["$APP/*", "$APP/**", "$APP/tree/*"]
- "scope": ["$DESKTOP/**", "$DESKTOP/test/"]
- "scope": ["$DESKTOP/*", "$DESKTOP/**", "$DESKTOP/test/*"]

And replaced Desktop in the Filetree.js Code. when i used App

## Error

```
FileTree.js:23 
        Uncaught (in promise) path not allowed on the configured scope: test
```

[Error Log from Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOnfv.png)

## I fixed the Problem above

### New Problem

I get no children now from the file entry

the File structure is:

#### tree

- parent1  :Folder

  - child1 :Folder
  - child2 :Folder
- parent2   :Folder

[Console- FileEntry with no children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa9CF.png)

Comment: where is the error log?

Comment: Oh yea sure here it is.

Comment: That looks like JavaScript, not Rust to me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the solution could be, but one idea might be to make the `readDir()` function not recursive like `await readDir('test', new Uint8Array([]), { dir: BaseDirectory.Desktop });` , or if you know what names the folders have, then read those separately. If your app only uses one type of file/file extension, then you can loop over the file entry and check if the file name ends with that extension (be sure to include the "." like ".exe") if not then read the directory.

Answer (score 0):

https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/fs/#fs.BaseDirectory.Home
"It is recommended to allowlist only the APIs you use for optimal bundle size and security."

Tauri.conf.json

```
  "fs": {
    "all":true,
    "scope": ["**"]
  }
```

src/main

```
import { readDir, BaseDirectory } from "@tauri-apps/api/fs";
// Reads the `Desktop` directory recursively
const entries = await readDir("", {
  dir: BaseDirectory.Desktop,
  recursive: true,
});

function processEntries(entries) {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    console.log(`Entry: ${entry.path}`);
    if (entry.children) {
      processEntries(entry.children);
    }
  }
}

processEntries(entries);
```

Further Reading:
https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/4130